# Python bottle key authentication system doesn't work after one person enters a key?

Tags: python, authentication, get, server, bottle

I'm trying to create a key system on my server that only lets a user proceed to a page if they have entered a valid key as a GET parameter. If the key is not valid or if no key is entered, they will be redirected to an "invalid key" page like below.

```
@route('/test/invalidkey')#key is invalid!
def index():
    return "Sorry, your API key is invalid! Message the admin if this is a problem."
```

On all of the routes, there is an `apply=[require_key]` parameter.

```
@route('/test/count', method='GET', apply=[require_key])
```

Here is the **require_key** method:

```
def require_key(fn):#check if api key is valid
    if not request.query.key:
        redirect('/test/invalidkey')
    return fn
```

Right now there is no API key. At the moment, I'm just checking to see if there has even been a ?key=hey parameter added to the url.

My problem is: Whenever someone tries accessing the page without an api key for the first time, it redirects to the invalid key page like it's supposed to. When someone accesses with a key for the first time, they proceed like it's supposed to. But... when someone accesses the page without a key parameter after they have already accessed the page has already been accessed with the key paramater, they can access the page without even needing a key GET parameter. Why does this happen?

If even one person accesses it with a key, anyone who accesses it without a key are allowed. Is this key GET parameter being stored and referenced again everytime? If so, how do I clear it?

I've read through the bottle documentation, but there is only a small block of text explaining the apply parameter and what it does. This doesn't go into any advanced details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using this guy's blog post. You'll have to use wayback machine to access it.

http://tumblr.kurttheviking.com/post/13053496552/using-decorators-to-require-sign-in-with-bottle-py

The require_key method should look more like this:

```
def require_uid(fn):
    def check_uid(**kwargs):   
        cookie_uid = request.get_cookie('cookieName', secret='cookieSignature')

        if cookie_uid:
            //do stuff with a user object
            return fn(**kwargs)
        else:
            redirect("/loginagain")

    return check_uid
```